# Which APIs are supported when hardware acceleration is enabled on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, hardware-acceleration

The Honeycomb docs are vague:

> When the hardware-accelerated renderer
>   is enabled, most operations in Canvas,
>   Paint, Xfermode, ColorFilter, Shader,
>   and Camera are accelerated.

Is there a definitive list of the exact APIs that are (and are not) supported when hardware acceleration is enabled? Some methods fail fast with exceptions, while other features simply render differently when acceleration is enabled.

For example, Canvas.clipPath(...) fails fast with an exception. Though the [clipPath API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath%28android.graphics.Path%29) makes no mention of this, it is easy enough to determine when testing on real hardware.

Other features render improperly without throwing exceptions, leading to difficult and time-consuming porting efforts. For example, I have a screen that uses a ComposeShader consisting of a RadialGradient and LinearGradient, using PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN. It looks beautiful without acceleration, but completely wrong when acceleration is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on getting a complete list published. The features not supported are:

- clipPath
- clipRegion
- clipRect with XOR or Difference op
- drawPicture
- drawPoints
- drawPosText
- drawTextOnPath
- drawTextPos
- drawVertices
- setMaskFilter
- setRasterizer

Edit: Read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) to know everything there is to know about hardware acceleration in Android 3.0.

However, what you are describing should work just fine. All gradients are supported, as well as all blending modes. Please report bugs with reproducible test cases for any issue you encounter and I'll get them fixed.

Comment: I checked the implementation and the hardware renderer currently supports only shaders of different types inside a ComposeShader. This means you can use a gradient + a bitmap, but not two bitmaps or two gradients. Note that for Views that do things not supported in hardware you can use setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) to force them to render in software.

Comment: Can you please add a webview in a scroll view and play some video in webview then scroll the view up and down, you will face a problem (sorry i cant explain that problem). my device is samsung galaxy tab 10.1"

Comment: @RomainGuy has this list changed for ICS and JB? couldn't find any info about it on the api docs or elsewhere.